# Are there any constructive axioms which disprove the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

I understand that the Continuum hypothesis is independent of ZFC, so that we may comfortably add either the continuum hypothesis or its negation to ZFC without creating any paradoxes (unless ZFC had them to begin with), and in fact there are several large Cardinal axioms that are inconsistent with CH.

My question is this: are there any proposed additions to ZFC which not only imply the negation of CH, but in fact allow for the explicit construction of a set with cardinality between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

If not, could such axioms be lurking about? Do we have any idea what such sets may "look" like?

I know that there are quite a few questions on CH lying about on this site, so if I missed a duplicate of this question I'd appreciate being directed to it as much as an answer.

Comment: Once you know that $CH$ is false (by any means), the set of wellorders on $\mathbb{N}$ modulo isomorphism has cardinality between that of the reals and the naturals. Specifically, take the set WO of subsets of  $\mathbb{N}  \times\mathbb{N}$ that are (as binary relations) wellorders of $\mathbb{N}$ . Now partition WO into isomorphism classes, obtaining $\Omega$. This $\Omega$ has always the smallest uncountable cardinal (that is, $\aleph_1$).  [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638838/subsets-of-the-reals-when-the-continuum-hypothesis-is-assumed-false) is related.

Comment: If the continuum hypothesis fails, there is always an explicit example of a set with cardinality between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, namely the cardinal $\aleph_1$ itself. It would be more challenging, however, to find an example which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I was not aware there was an explicit construction of $\aleph_1$, which betrays some of my ignorance here, thank you @CarlMummert

Comment: No problem. Every cardinal number with a finite subscript is definable. The set of ordinals is definable, and the order relation on ordinals is definable. Formally, we will say something like: $\aleph_{i+1}$ is the unique set which is an ordinal, is a subset of the cardinal of $P(\aleph_i)$, and has cardinality strictly larger than $\aleph_i$. This uses the usual representation of cardinal numbers where each cardinal is the first ordinal of a given cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carl's comments are exactly right. However, in a different sense there are indeed serious obstacles to finding "explicit" sets with intermediate cardinality:

> Every analytic set $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the *perfect set property* - that is, either is countable or contains a nonempty closed set with no isolated points (and hence has size continuum).

The analytic (=${\bf \Sigma^1_1}$) sets are those which are the continuous image of some Borel set. The situation gets worse if we assume large cardinals:

> Assuming some large cardinals, every *projective* set of reals has the perfect set property.

The projective sets of reals are all those which can be described using quantification over reals. In practice, basically every set of reals you can think of is Borel - that is, *much simpler* than analytic.

If you are interested in results like these, you should look at **Descriptive Set Theory**.